# Add to commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

I have made the following diagram

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\xymatrix{
    & &
    {X}
    {\ar[dll]|-{\pi_0}}
    {\ar[dl]|-{\pi_1}}
    {\ar@{.>}[d]}
    {\ar[dr]|-{\pi_{i-1}}}
    {\ar[drr]|-{\pi_i}}
    {\ar@{.>}[drrr]}
    %= \varprojlim\{X_i, \varphi_i\}
    & & &
    {(D_\infty)}
    \\
    {X_0}
    &
    {\ar@{}[l]^{\phantom{\varphi_0}}}
    {\ar[l]^{\varphi_0}}
    {X_1}
    &
    {\phantom{\ar@{}[l]}}
    {\ar@{.>}[l]}
    {\cdots}
    &
    {\ar@{.>}[l]}
    {X_{i-1}}
    &
    {\ar[l]^{\varphi_{i-1}}}
    {X_i}
    &
    \ar@{.>}[l]
    {\cdots}
}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I want to make it look like this:
[image]

Any idea how I can do that with what I already have?  Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the problem with extending the diagram, given that the already existing code contains all elements that you need?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
    & &
    {X}
    {\ar[dll]|-{\pi_0}}
    {\ar[dl]|-{\pi_1}}
    {\ar@{.>}[d]}
    {\ar[dr]|-{\pi_{i-1}}}
    {\ar[drr]|-{\pi_i}}
    {\ar@{.>}[drrr]}
    %= \varprojlim\{X_i, \varphi_i\}
    & & &
    {(D_\infty)}
    \\
    {X_0}
    {\ar[d]|-{h_0}}
    &
    {\ar@{}[l]^{\phantom{\varphi_0}}}
    {\ar[l]^{\varphi_0}}
    {X_1}
    {\ar[d]|-{h_1}}
    &
    {\phantom{\ar@{}[l]}}
    {\ar@{.>}[l]}
    {\cdots}
    {\ar@{.>}[d]}
    &
    {\ar@{.>}[l]}
    {X_{i-1}}
    {\ar[d]|-{h_{i-1}}}
    &
    {\ar[l]^{\varphi_{i-1}}}
    {X_i}
    {\ar[d]|-{h_i}}
    &
    \ar@{.>}[l]
    {\cdots}
    {\ar@{.>}[d]}
    \\
    {Y}
    &
    {\ar[l]^{\text{id}}}
    {Y}
    &
    {\ar@{.>}[l]}
    {\cdots}
    &
    {\ar@{.>}[l]}
    {Y}
    &
    {\ar[l]^{\text{id}}}
    {Y}
    &
    \ar@{.>}[l]
    {\cdots}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is so obvious to me now, I don't know why I didn't try it like this.  Thanks!